# How to maintain state when toggling between screens in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React app where I toggle between screens using a state variable. When I switch to a screen and then switch back, the state of the previous screen seems to have been reset. For example, if I have a counter on Screen 1 and I increment it, then switch to Screen 2 and back to Screen 1, the counter has been reset to 0. How can I maintain the state of each screen even when I toggle between them?

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [screen, setScreen] = useState("screen1");

  return (
    <div>
      {screen === "screen1" ? (
        <Screen1 />
      ) : (
        <Screen2 />
      )}
      <button onClick={() => setScreen(screen === "screen1" ? "screen2" : "screen1")}>
        Toggle Screen
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Screen1() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Screen 1</h1>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Screen2() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Screen 2</h1>
      <p>Some other content</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your `App` component, you're conditionally switching between rendering screen1 and screen2. Each time you switch to one, the other unmounts - and in doing so, its state is erased. When you switch back to it, it goes through its initial mount all over again, at which point the state is starting fresh at 0. It has no memory of what it used to be.

There are a few approaches here. The best would probably be to instead move the `count` useState hook to the parent component `App`, and then pass the `count` variable and `setCount` function to the child component you want it in via props.

There could be a theoretical use case in which you want to persist the components entirely, in which case instead of conditionally rendering the two, you could make each of them conditionally invisible using the `display: none` css attribute. In that case, state would persist as it's not being unmounted when you switch. However, I'd say in most cases it would be inadvisable to keep both elements on the DOM. I'd go with option 1, probably.